# Circle: How it can be proven, that always there is a number m such that after m*k moves one can return to the starting point n(i)?

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, circles, gcd-and-lcm

Given a circle and **n** points in it such that these points are dividing the circle into equal parts. There is also a positive number **k** which can be less/more than **n**. It is allowed to move (only clockwise or only counterclockwise) across the perimeter of the circle by a step equal to **k** started from some point **n(i)**. How it can be proven, that always there is a number **m** such that after **m*k** moves one can return to the starting point **n(i)**?

My approach is the following:
for any **n** and **k**, always exists **lcm(n, k)**. It means that we can write the following expression: **c*n = m*k** or **lcm(n, k) = m*k*** . This is, in turn, means that **mk** contains at least one complete **n** so at some point it has been reaching the starting point. But I'm not sure about this approach.

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: My approach is the following once lcm(n,k) = m*k then after m*k steps it is already in the starting point.

Comment: Please add these details with an [edit].